# After 15.10 upgrade NetworkManager using 30% CPU

Tags: network-manager, cpu-load, 15.10

Just upgraded a 3rd Gen Lenovo Carbon X1 from 15.04 to 15.10 and I noticed a rise in CPU usage.

/usr/sbin/NetworkManager is using ~35% constantly and /lib/systemd/systemd-journald seems to rise when NetworkManager is started (drops when it is stopped).

Turning of the wireless adapter does nothing. Turning off bluetooth also does nothing. No LAN is connected.

Stopping the service fixes the problem, obviously, but this is not a viable option.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had a custom config file

> /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/local

with one line

> cache-size=300

When I removed this file (experimenting), network manager instantly stopped using CPU and returned to normal. The problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: It's magic! ...

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrading to 15.10. I have an empty dir /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/

Comment: @HongboZhu same here.

Comment: @HongboZhu My issue was that NM tried to start dnsmasq on 127.0.1.1:53, but that port was already taken by `dnsmasq.service`. The solution for me was `sudo systemctl disable dnsmasq.service`

Comment: @joar Thanks for the info. But it does not help me :(. I still have NM running with ~17% CPU.  Disabling WIFI eases CPU usage. Interestingly, re-enable WIFI never works. Restart is required.

Comment: @HongboZhu check what the logging says in `sudo systemctl status NetworkManager`

Comment: @joar In the CGroup: I still see: `/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --...`  Ping IP successful, but no DNS service.

Comment: I solved the problem by commenting out `dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that `NetworkManager.service` tried to start dnsmasq on 127.0.1.1:53, but that port was already taken by `dnsmasq.service`. The solution for me was `sudo systemctl disable dnsmasq.service`

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem. Another symptom was if I suspended the system, then the DNS failed to work after being awaken from suspend. What helped me was to comment out `dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```